# find if an element of 1 array is present in another array without sorting

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have 1 vector representing some of the days of a week

```
daysweek = [5 6 7 1 2 3]; % (1 = sunday,  2= monday,..., 7 = saturday)
```

I want to count how many sundays, mondays etc are present in my vector.

What I do is define a vector:

```
uniquedays = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];%sorted so I can use hist
```

count how many instances present in my original vector "daysweek" exists in uniquedays.

```
countdays = hist(daysweek, uniquedays);
```

countdays will be then `1 1 1 0 1 1 1.`

My problem is that I would like to have countdays with the first element referring to Monday and not to Sunday so it should be `1 1 0 1 1 1 1` (like if uniquedays is 2 3 4 5 6 7 1)

Thanks

Comment: `countdays = [countdays(2:end) countdays(1)]` will rotate the array one place to the left. If you do this after everything else, countdays will have Monday first, though uniquedays won't be changed.

Comment: o_O' sorry! I was thinking something more complicated!

Comment: anyway is there a way to use hist or something related without sorting the array?

Comment: Is the end goal to plot a histogram, or to count occurrences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `circshift`:

```
countdays = hist(daysweek, uniquedays); 
countdays = circshift(countdays,[0 -1]);
```

Comment: Don't think that'll work: `Edges vector must be monotonically non-decreasing.`

Comment: Oh, yeah.  Should be a shift of the output (fixed).  Anyway, use circshift was my point.